# Failed to copy full contents binding_classes.json in multimodule project

Tags: android, gradle

I have a multimodule project.

It worked fine for some times, but now I have this error from time to time:

```
Failed to copy full contents from 'C:\StudioProjects\project1\android\features\media\integration\build\intermediates\data_binding_base_class_log_artifact\debug\out\com.example.media-binding_classes.json' to 'C:\StudioProjects\project1\android\features\authorized_zone\feature\build\intermediates\data_binding_base_class_logs_dependency_artifacts\debug\com.example.media-binding_classes.json'
```

`Clean & Rebuild` soves the problem. Sometimes several rebuilds is required.

The error was initially in one module, some random changes in one of its layout seems to fix the problem. But now the same error appears in two other modules.

What doews this error means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while of searching for the answer I've faced a simple solution to my problem.

My gradle plugin version was `7.2.1`. After I've updated the version to `7.4.1` the problem was resloved.

I've used gradle version `7.5` and it is supported by `7.4.1` plugin. So no additional changes required in my case.

Hope this could help someone.